# Client Side Validation not performing MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, validation, client-side-validation

**LAYOUT**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <!-- Apple devices fullscreen -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <!-- Apple devices fullscreen -->
    <meta names="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />

    <title>New Indus Goods - Loagin</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/css/bootstrap.min.css")"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/css/plugins/icheck/all.css")"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/css/style.css")"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/css/themes.css")"/>
     <link href="@Url.Content("~/Styles/view_specific_style.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

   <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/jquery.min.js")"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/plugins/nicescroll/jquery.nicescroll.min.js")"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/plugins/validation/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/plugins/validation/additional-methods.min.js")"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/plugins/icheck/jquery.icheck.min.js")"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/bootstrap.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/eakroko.js")"></script>

    <!--[if lte IE 9]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/plugins/placeholder/jquery.placeholder.min.js")"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('input, textarea').placeholder();
            });
        </script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/img/favicon.ico" />
    <!-- Apple devices Homescreen icon -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="~/img/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png" />

</head>

<body class='login'>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>
            <a href="index.html">
                <img src="@Url.Content("~/img/logo-big.png")" alt="" class='retina-ready' width="59" height="49">New Indus Goods</a>
        </h1>

        <div id="body" class="login-body">
        @RenderSection("featured",required:false)
            <section class="content-wrapper">
            @RenderBody()
            </section>


        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**VIEW**

```
@model Test1.Models.UserProfile

@{

      Layout = "~/Views/_LayoutPage1.cshtml";

    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Test1.Models.UserProfile lol = ViewBag.Profile;

}

@section featured
{
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Input"))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
<div class="content-wrapper">

    <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="email controls">
                       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>



<p>lol what is is</p>
</fieldset>
  <p>

            <input type="submit" value="Save" />

        </p>

}
}
<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back To Index", "Index");
</div>
```

Server side validation is performed but client side is not happening! please tell me what am I missing here?? I have tried finding a solution on Google but failed. I am new to MVC so kindly help me! Page goes back for POST then come back and says Name field is required, why it is not validating before POSTING BACK??

Comment: Check the basics first - have you added `<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />` to web.config appSettings?

Comment: Still client side validation is not performing.. why??

Comment: Page goes back for POST then come back and says Email is required, why it is not validating before POSTING BACK??

Comment: You aren't referencing `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` from the layout. `jquery.validate.js` is not enough.

Comment: Umm okay as i have created a NEW EMPTY PROJECT i dont think i have jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js file anywhere in my project? rite?

Comment: Install the `Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation` NuGet package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to add

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

in page-related web.config too :)